# Limit execution time of python eval() function in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-3.x, eval

I have table of employees and it has a column with an expression that has to be executed. This expression is provided by the admin of each employee and it is manipulated by some variables. Now, I'm using python's `eval()` function to evaluate this expression.

I need to protect from expressions like `10 ** 10000000000` or something like that.

I tried to use threads and UNIX signals to abort execution, but python told me that signals can only be used in main thread.

Also, I think that spawning background process each time can be quite expensive.

Comment: eval has much more serious security problems than expressions which take a long time: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html
Do you really have to use eval? Why do you have a table with arbitrary expressions?

Comment: This field contains expression to calculate employee yearly salary bonus. It can be arbitrary for each each employee in each company

Comment: Can that consist of things other than basic operations like multiplication and addition?